# create-react-app stuck on outdated dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

Create-react-app is failing with the error below. 
It seems like react-scripts is expecting an older version of a dependency. This seems like an interface problem because I'm not able to use the arrow keys to select the new version as it suggests.

I'm able to install "require-from-string" 2.02 in other directories with 'yarn add' and 'npm install'. I'm using OSX 10.12.6, node v9.2.0, and react-scripts 1.0.17.

**Terminal response to running "create-react-app":**

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

yarn add v1.3.2
info No lockfile found.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
Couldn't find any versions for "require-from-string" that matches 
"^1.1.0"

? Please choose a version of "require-from-string" from this list: (Use 
arrow keys)

❯ 2.0.2
```

***I'm not able to select the version above. Hitting 'enter' returns the following: ***

```
error Received malformed response from registry for "pinkie-promise". 

The registry may be down.

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about 
this command.

Error: Received malformed response from registry for "timed-out". The 
registry may be down.
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:48907:15
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at step (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:92:30)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:110:14
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at new F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:29389:28)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:89:12
at Function.findVersionInRegistryResponse 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:48946:7)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:48963:28
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)

Aborting installation.
yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts --cwd ~/apps/memory-
game has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Done.
```

Comment: npm is having some troubles. Read more here https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/41zfb8qpvrdj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an ongoing problem with npm packages that happened today. You can read more about this problem and get the latest status [here in the npm website.](https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/41zfb8qpvrdj)
Also [here on GitHub](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19534)

It seems we have to wait until they fix the problem. 

**EDITED**: The problem is solved by npm

Comment: Does this sort of thing happen often? I started using create-react-app a couple weeks ago.

Comment: @Gerard the last large incident was left-pad, March 2016

Comment: @Gerard Not really often but it happens with any package manager sometimes and it's not avoidable. Don't worry and keep going